# how to know which node is dropped after using keras dropout layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

From [nick blog](https://nickcdryan.com/2017/06/13/dropconnect-implementation-in-python-and-tensorflow/) it is clear that in dropout layer of CNN model we drop some nodes on the basis of bernoulli. But how to verify it, i.e. how to check which node is not selected. In DropConnect we leave some weights so I think with the help of `model.get_weights()` we can verify, but how in the case of dropout layer.

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(2, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Another question is that it is mention in [keras](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout) that dropout rate should float b/w 0 to 1. But for above model when I take dropout rate = 1.25, then also my model is working, how this happens?

Comment: Please provide answer

Comment: Why do you need to check it?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your second question, if you see [Keras code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py), in the `call` method form `Dropout` class:

```
def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    if 0. < self.rate < 1.:
        noise_shape = self._get_noise_shape(inputs)

        def dropped_inputs():
            return K.dropout(inputs, self.rate, noise_shape,
                             seed=self.seed)
        return K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs, inputs,
                                training=training)
    return inputs
```

This means that if the `rate` is not between 0 and 1, it will do nothing.

Comment: ok, got it, that it not give error but it will do nothing. and i want to check it, for better understanding of cnn model, and to show students.