# How to use Keras layers without making model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I want to use Keras layers [pooling layers](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) without making a model. Every time I see example related to Keras,I see them in model form, like as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(2, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
....

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,)
```

This way, first we define `input` and then model then `compile` and last `fit`. but let say I have to perform maxpooling operation and I have only 1 image of size 56*64 with gray scale, i.e input in 4d tensor form (1,56,64,1). Then how can I perform maxpooling operation using Keras `MaxPooling2D` layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a model with only `MaxPooling2D` and do `predict` (with no `fit`):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), input_shape=input_shape))
model.compile('adadelta')

pooled = model.predict(image)
```

The `compile` doesn't affect at all.

#### Full code

Example from @Hitesh comment:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np

image=np.random.rand(1, 56, 64, 1)
input_shape=(56,64,1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), input_shape=input_shape))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

pooled = model.predict(image)
```

Comment: this works, example code is following: from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
image=np.random.rand(1, 56, 64, 1)
input_shape=(56,64,1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), input_shape=input_shape))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
pooled = model.predict(image)

Comment: can you please look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630178/how-to-know-which-node-is-dropped-after-using-keras-dropout-layer. i am not getting answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using using functional API: just define `input`, then do something like this:

```
maxpooled = MaxPooling2D(...)(input)
maxpooled.eval(feed_dict={input: input_image}, session=...)
```

BTW using Keras for that is kind of an overkill, since it's a toolkit for building `models`. You can just easily do it without keras using tensorflow or any other deep learning framework.

Comment: I know tf.nn.max_pool is useful, but again i donot know how to use it.